# What type of database to use with AngularJS and JSON

Tags: php, database, json, angularjs

Haven't been able to find any resources which explore this type of issue with Angular, so feel free to link me in the right direction if you know of anything.

I'm building an online store for mobile (it's only mobile at this stage) with Angular.

At the core of the system are products (each with a name, designer, description, colour, price, category, store location and a few others).

I'm currently storing this all in JSON files and loading that into Angular, but the more products I add the more unmanageable this is becoming.

**What I'd like to do**:

I'd like a database that I can send some queries to (example: "mens, shirt,

The only backend system I've had any exposure to is MySQL (and not much at that). I know enough PHP to get myself around, I'd say beginner-intermediate (I'm a front-end dev by trade).

Is this sort've thing best suited to any particular type of database? And is there any particular "playing nice" that any do with AngularJS?

Comment: I'm not well versed in databases but depending on your database needs - it shouldn't matter. Angular plays so well with JSON the only thing you have to worry about is getting your back end to spit out the DB stuff in JSON format. TLDR: Doesn't really matter unless you are looking for something specific within DB software

Comment: Well the queries would be coming from Angular/javascript. As above, I'm really unfamiliar with databases so don't know what would play nicely with angular in that regard (like if the query comes from a directive or filter)

Comment: i recommend using mongodb

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal Any reason why?

Comment: reads in mongodb are fastes then couchdb and your application seems to be 90% reads

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal Interesting, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you had a look at [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/)?

Data stored in CouchDB is stored natively as JSON, so it flows nicely through to web apps since you get to communicate with the database as JSON.

[CornerCouch](https://github.com/eddelplus/CornerCouch) is an AngularJS module written specifically for this purpose, although I have not played with it myself.

Comment: Interesting, taking a look now. This looks to be a table-less database. I liked the idea of relational tables because I have products that belong to different stores (and different categories). So if `product a, b and c` all have a `name, price, description` and belong to `store: foo`, and `store foo` has `location: 'lng/lat', address: 2 fake st`, I want the two to be linked. It seems like this is not possible with a non-relational DB, no?

Comment: A "Document" (aka record in a relational database) still gets a Unique ID so you can certainly store references and combine data. It's true that alot of the beauty of this type of database lies in being able to inline related data, and having a schema-less layout (making it much easier to implement an item having certain attributes that another similar item does not).

Comment: Have fun trying to implement authentication with CouchDB. I've been trying for weeks to get it working and no luck. Switching to MongoDB.